# Xcode fails to automatically run a newly created macOS project

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, macos-sierra

Here's how this issue can be reproduced:

1. Open Xcode;
2. Create a new macOS Cocoa application (not document-based, not using core data or any test frameworks);
3. Click run (or press Cmd+R).

The app will fail to run, with the following showing in the console:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __pthread_atfork_child_handlers
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
(lldb)
```

The program stops at a line of assembly code, marked by `->` as follows:

```
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
    0x1000359e4 <+0>:  movl   $0x2000209, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000209 
    0x1000359e9 <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x1000359ec <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x1000359ee <+10>: jae    0x1000359f8               ; <+20>
    0x1000359f0 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x1000359f3 <+15>: jmp    0x100035300               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x1000359f8 <+20>: retq   
    0x1000359f9 <+21>: nop    
    0x1000359fa <+22>: nop    
    0x1000359fb <+23>: nop
```

I noticed that the built product (the *.app executable) is runnable, if I show it in Finder, and double click.

Furthermore, if I edit the Run scheme, and set "Launch" to "Wait for executable to be launched" instead of the default "Automatically", I can debug the app normally by:

1. Press Cmd+R. Xcode shows "Waiting to attach to xxx";
2. Double click xxx.app in Finder to launch the app;
3. Xcode works as normal.

So the problem seems to be that Xcode failed to attach to the executable automatically.

How should I fix this?

My specs:

- Xcode 8.3.1
- Swift 3.0.1
- macOS 10.12.4
- Intel CPU

Comment: I tried your steps but mine is working. Could you possibly have a corrupted Xcode installation or something weird like a case-sensitive filesystem? (I know it sounds silly, but two years ago I tried and some games stopped working!) Do you want me to zip my project and send to you?

Comment: exactly same problem here. Exact same error and built product runs. Did you already sort it out in some way ? Thanks for any help.

Comment: @stefat No. Seems like a rare issue.

Comment: I am seeing this issue too. However, I just restored from a Time Machine backup from an older Mac mini to a new Mac Pro. Wonder if that's somehow related (maybe a file got corrupted or is missing?).

Comment: @kainjow My issues started after recovering from my Time Machine backup too! I shall add this to my question description.

Comment: @YuhuanJiang do you happen to have Homebrew installed?

Comment: @kainjow Yes I do. Why is it related? Have you found something?

Comment: @YuhuanJiang unfortunately no. Initially I had issues using lldb on the command line related to Python which was installed with Homebrew, but resolving that didn't change the Xcode issue.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. My colleague suggested reapplying the current macOS combo update and that worked for me. Since macOS 10.12.4 is the latest I used this:

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1910?locale=en_US